# HTML5 Context/Canvas - when to call draw on the context

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, html5-animation

I'm writing a little object oriented style javasscript demo -- just to draw a bunch of balls moving around the screen.  nothing fancy, no collision detection or anything at this point. Consider it safe to assume my Ball.js class is good.

My question amounts to this:  Where should I call ball.draw(context) ?  The only way to get balls drawn to the screen the way I set it up seems to be by placing the call in generateBalls().  But that means each ball is just drawn once.

So I'd really appreaciate it if someone could point out the error of my ways here.  This isn't homework - just trying to get a better handle on javascript and canvas.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="ball.js"></script>
<script src="utils.js"></script>
...
    <canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="480"></canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.addEventListener('load', eventWindowLoaded, false);

        function eventWindowLoaded() {
            canvasApp();    
        }

        function canvasSupport() {
            return true;    
        }

        function canvasApp() {
            if(!canvasSupport()) {
                return; 
            }
        }
        console.log("app entered");
        var numBalls = 45;
        //var numBalls = demo.numberofballs.value;
        var maxSize = 8;
        var minSize = 5; 
        var maxSpeed = maxSize + 5;
        var balls = new Array();
        var tempBall;
        var tempX;
        var tempY;
        var tempSpeed;
        var tempAngle;
        var tempRadius;
        var tempRadians;
        var tempXunits;
        var tempYunits;

        canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        context = canvas.getContext("2d");

        generateBalls();

        setInterval(drawScreen, 33);

        function generateBalls() {
            console.log("Make some balls");
            for(var index = 0; index < numBalls; index++) {
                var tempRadius = Math.floor(Math.random()*maxSize)+minSize;
                var ball = new Ball(tempRadius, "#000000"); 
                ball.x = tempRadius * 2 + (Math.floor(Math.random()*canvas.width) -  tempRadius * 2);
                ball.y = tempRadius * 2 + (Math.floor(Math.random()*canvas.height) - tempRadius * 2);
                ball.speed = maxSpeed - tempRadius;
                ball.angle = Math.floor(Math.random()*360);
                ball.dx = Math.cos(tempRadians) * tempSpeed;
                ball.dy = Math.sin(tempRadians) * tempSpeed;
                // here outputted balls but a stupid place to put it LOL
                balls.push(ball);



            }

        }

        function drawScreen() {
            console.log("draw screen");



            // loop through all balls and adjust their position
            // a BallManager could do this more cleanly
            for(var index = 0; index < balls.length; index++) {

                context.fillStyle="#EE00EE";
                context.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);

                // Box
                context.strokeStyle = "#ff0043";
                context.strokeRect(1,1,canvas.width-2, canvas.height-2);

                // place balls
                context.fillStyle = "#ff8783";
                console.log("ball mover loop in drawscreen");
                // no var ball now

                ball = balls[index];
                ball.x += ball.dx;
                ball.y += ball.dy;
                ball.draw(context);
                //checkBoundaries(balls[index]);
                if(ball.x > canvas.width || ball.x < 0) {
                ball.angle = 180 - ball.angle;
                updateBall(ball);   
                    } else if(ball.y > canvas.height || ball.y < 0) {
                        ball.angle = 360 - ball.angle;
                        updateBall(ball);   
                        //ball.draw(context);
                }

            }

        }   

        //function checkBoundaries(ball) {
            //console.log("Check Bounds: " + " " + "ball.x: " + ball.x + " " + //"ball.y: " + ball.y);

        //}

        function updateBall(ball) {
            ball.radians = ball.angle * Math.PI / 180;
            ball.dx = Math.cos(ball.radians) * ball.speed;
            ball.dy = Math.sin(ball.radians) * ball.speed;
            //ball.draw(context);
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you for your advice,
Marc

Comment: I think, one of possible approaches could be to introduce a function for entire screen update, which clears background and draws all balls on their current positions. This function should be invoked via setInterval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example contains more than one error, please check your modified code. It works, but you must extend and correct it.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    // next lines is a Ball() implementation code
    Ball = function(radius,color) {
        this.radius=radius;
        this.color=color;
    };
    Ball.prototype.x=0;
    Ball.prototype.y=0;
    Ball.prototype.speed=0;
    Ball.prototype.angle=0;
    Ball.prototype.dx=0;
    Ball.prototype.dy=0;
    Ball.prototype.radius=10;
    Ball.prototype.color="#000";
    Ball.prototype.draw=function() {

        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(this.x,this.y,this.radius,0,Math.PI*2,true);
        context.lineWidth = 5;
        context.strokeStyle = this.color; // line color
        context.stroke();
        context.closePath();
    };

    window.addEventListener('load', eventWindowLoaded, false);

    function eventWindowLoaded() {
        canvasApp();    

        //console.log("app entered");
        window.canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        window.context = canvas.getContext("2d");

        generateBalls();
        // if you want to use setInterval() instead replace next line
        setTimeout(drawScreen, 33);
    }

    function canvasSupport() {
        return true;    
    }

    function canvasApp() {
        if(!canvasSupport()) {
            return;
        }
    }

    var numBalls = 45;
    //var numBalls = demo.numberofballs.value;
    var maxSize = 8;
    var minSize = 5;
    var maxSpeed = maxSize + 5;
    var balls = new Array();
    var tempBall;
    var tempX;
    var tempY;
    var tempSpeed;
    var tempAngle;
    var tempRadius;
    var tempRadians;
    var tempXunits;
    var tempYunits;

    function generateBalls() {
        //console.log("Make some balls");
        for(var index = 0; index < numBalls; index++) {
            var tempRadius = Math.floor(Math.random()*maxSize)+minSize;
            var tempRadians = Math.random()*Math.PI;
            var tempSpeed = 10;
            var ball = new Ball(tempRadius, "#000000");
            ball.x = tempRadius * 2 + (Math.floor(Math.random()*canvas.width) -  tempRadius * 2);
            ball.y = tempRadius * 2 + (Math.floor(Math.random()*canvas.height) - tempRadius * 2);
            ball.speed = maxSpeed - tempRadius;
            ball.angle = Math.floor(Math.random()*360);
            ball.dx = Math.cos(tempRadians) * tempSpeed;
            ball.dy = Math.sin(tempRadians) * tempSpeed;
            // here outputted balls but a stupid place to put it LOL
            balls.push(ball);
        }
    }

    function drawScreen() {
        console.log("draw screen");


        context.fillStyle="#EE00EE";
        context.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);

        // Box
        context.strokeStyle = "#ff0043";
        context.strokeRect(1,1,canvas.width-2, canvas.height-2);

        // loop through all balls and adjust their position
        // a BallManager could do this more cleanly
        for(var index = 0; index < balls.length; index++) {
            // place balls
            context.fillStyle = "#008700";
            //console.log("ball mover loop in drawscreen");
            // no var ball now

            ball = balls[index];
            ball.x += ball.dx;
            ball.y += ball.dy;
            ball.draw(context);
            //checkBoundaries(balls[index]);
            if(ball.x > canvas.width || ball.x < 0) {
                ball.angle = 180 - ball.angle;
                updateBall(ball);   
            } else if(ball.y > canvas.height || ball.y < 0) {
                ball.angle = 360 - ball.angle;
                 updateBall(ball);   
                //ball.draw(context);
            }

        }
        // if you want to use setInterval() instead remove next line
        setTimeout(drawScreen, 33);
    }   

    //function checkBoundaries(ball) {
        //console.log("Check Bounds: " + " " + "ball.x: " + ball.x + " " + //"ball.y: " + ball.y);

    //}

    function updateBall(ball) {
        ball.radians = ball.angle * Math.PI / 180;
        ball.dx = Math.cos(ball.radians) * ball.speed;
        ball.dy = Math.sin(ball.radians) * ball.speed;
        //ball.draw(context);
    }

  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="480" style="background:red;"></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QVgZx/2/

Comment: I see how you Ball would work here but this is how I set mine up -- and how I have seen it done by others often as well.

Comment: @Marc H: For your code: 1) is a bad technic to place `<script>` tag inside any tag other than `<head>`. 2) `Ball()` implementation: important two lines in Ball constructor, draw() method and declaring of all Ball members with initial values. 3) _"Application start code"_  moved into window load event handler function (eventWindowLoaded in your code). 4) Fixed generateBalls(): added tempRadiand and tempSpeed variables setting. 5) In drawScreen() background drawing code moved from _for_ loop to top

Answer (score 1):

Just necroing the thread to add a bit of an update for anyone new to canvas who arrives here:

Stan recommended creating a function to draw each of the balls at one spot in code; this is good for a number of reasons, it makes the animation smoother, and the code far easier to debug/maintain.

I would disagree with Stan, however, when it comes to using setInterval to trigger this... although, that might very well have been common practice when Stan wrote it.

Now, however, we use requestAnimationFrame.

This will sync your painting with the rest of the browser.

This allows your code to run far faster since every time the browser draws something, it has to go through the entire page again to determine where everything will go, just in case something moved.

Using setInterval leaves no guarantee as to when it will fire, and certainly doesn't time it to coincide with the browser's screen refresh.

This means it is drawing a little, reconfiguring the page, drawing a little more, reconfiguring again, drawing some more... and again and again.  This is very bad, and very slow.

Using requestAnimationFrame, however, allows the browser to call your function whenever it is about to redraw the screen anyway... which means a single redraw, and a single refresh.

Far faster, far cleaner.

It works slightly differently, but is actually very simple.

```
requestAnimationFrame(redraw);
```

This registers your function 'redraw' with requestAnimationFrame so that the next time the browser wants to redraw the window, your function will be called.

The one gotcha with this is that it will only call your function ONCE... in that way, it is like a setTimeout rather than a setInterval.

This way, you don't need to pass around the timer variable to stop the animation; it will stop because it stopped being called.

However, to ensure that your animation continues to run, just put that very same call at the bottom of your redraw function:

```
function redraw()
{
    var blah, blahblah;
    ...

    requestAnimationFrame(redraw);
}
```

You can also set this conditionally, to run your animation until it is finished, then stop:

```
function redraw()
{
    ...

    if (!finished) requestAnimationFrame(redraw);
}
```

Mozilla reference [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame), Paul Irish [HERE](http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/), and Chris Coyer [HERE](http://css-tricks.com/using-requestanimationframe/).